# RSA private key format

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I was trying to find a way to replicate the session-id decoding of mega.co.nz in Ruby using OpenSSL. But, unfortunately, I'm not a cryptography expert.

The problem is I don't understand/recognise the private key format

This is what their code to decompose the private key looks like (https://eu.static.mega.co.nz/crypto.js):

```js
// decompose private key
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    var l = ((privk.charCodeAt(0)*256+privk.charCodeAt(1)+7)>>3)+2;

    rsa_privk[i] = mpi2b(privk.substr(0,l));
    if (typeof rsa_privk[i] == 'number') break;
    privk = privk.substr(l);
}
```

`privk` itself is 656 bytes long (include eight dashes padding at the end).

After the 'decomposition' they use the decomposed parts to decrypt the session-id (https://eu.static.mega.co.nz/rsa.js):

```js
// Compute m**d mod p*q for RSA private key operations.

function RSAdecrypt(m (encrypted session-id), d (rsa_privk[2]), p (rsa_privk[0]), q (rsa_privk[1]), u (rsa_privk[3]))
```

How to convert this key so OpenSSL knows how to use it?

Comment: Do you have a test key to show what the key looks like?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL supports different key formats, including [PEM/X.509](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) and [PKCS8](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS).

The ruby standard library includes an [OpenSSL binding](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html).

Using the method provided [in this post](http://blog.internautdesign.com/2007/11/2/ruby-openssl-rsa-public-key-from-modulus-and-exponent) you can create the key from the exponent and then use for example

```
key.to_pem()
```

to convert it to an X.509-formatted string.